# Setup.exe prerequisite fails with "Downloading failed with HRESULT -2146697208"

Tags: installation, setup-project, bootstrapper

I had created a setup.exe bootstrapper a while ago and it seems to be working fine on windows 10. Recently I tried to run it on a new trial vhd for Windows 2012-r2 (downloaded off ms site) and the setup fails with the above error:

> An error occurred downloading the following resource:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177916&clcid=0x409
> Date: 1/16/2021 8:51:28 PM See the setup log file located at
> 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\VSDFA0C.tmp\install.log'
> for more information.

The last few lines of the log file is:

> Copying files to temporary directory
> "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\VSDFA0C.tmp" Downloading
> files to "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\VSDFA0C.tmp"
> (1/16/2021 8:51:28 PM) Downloading
> 'vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe' from
> 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177916&clcid=0x409' to
> 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\VSDFA0C.tmp' Download
> completed at 1/16/2021 8:51:28 PM Downloading failed with
> HRESULT=-2146697208

This is working on a bare windows 10 machine and I think it was working before in windows 2012 machine also (although I am not sure). I read some articles in the forum asking to change settings in the IE to make it work. In my case this is not possible as I intend to distribute this setup.exe to customer to install a product on their machine.

Any ideas how this can be addressed in the setup.exe bootstrapper? BTW: I can download the redistributable from the browser without any issue.

Comment: I find that if I disable the ssl page caching in IE, it works (https://github.com/microsoft/idfix/issues/20#issuecomment-704497252) but how can I do it in the setup program?